# Mini sudoku (4x4) generator efficiency

Tags: python, sudoku

I have a code that can generate a 4x4 sudoku matrix, by random generation of numbers. To do this, i create a `Matrix4` class that can detect its elements by its rows, columns, and submatrices for sudoku puzzle.

The method used here is by inputting a random matrx (4x4) and then shuffle the numbers in (1,2,3,4) to be randomly put in the matrix until it became a solved sudoku matrix.

The `sudoku_gen(Matrix,f)` will generate a sudoku matrix with `Matrix` as a `Matrix4` object, and `f` as the frequency for the shuffle.

I intend to only use minimum number of modules,only `copy` and `random` are used here.

The weakness is that, it is slow. I would appreciate for feedbacks on this. Thanks.

```
#### 9 January 2018,
#### Author : Arief Anbiya
#### Description : A code to generate a minimum sudoku-matrix (4x4).
####               The method used is still naive.
####               The emphasis is on the short code,
####               and only two modules used : copy and random.  
####               This is my first code uploaded in GitHub

import copy
import random

def shuffle(x, freq):
    y = copy.deepcopy(x);
    for i in range(0,freq):
        idx = int(random.uniform(0, len(x)));
        val = y.pop(idx);
        y.append(val);
    z = copy.deepcopy(y);
    return z

class Matrix4:
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.mat = copy.deepcopy(matrix);
        self.rows = self.mat;
        self.columns = [[i[j] for i in self.rows] for j in range(0, 4)];
        sub_1 = [self.rows[0][0], self.rows[0][1], \
                      self.rows[1][0], self.rows[1][1]];
        sub_2 = [self.rows[0][2], self.rows[0][3], \
                     self.rows[1][2], self.rows[1][3]];
        sub_3 = [self.rows[2][0], self.rows[2][1], \
                     self.rows[3][0], self.rows[3][1]];
        sub_4 = [self.rows[2][2], self.rows[2][3], \
                     self.rows[3][2], self.rows[3][3]];
        self.submats = [sub_1, sub_2, sub_3, sub_4];
    def show(self):
        print('--Rows--');
        print(self.rows);
        print('--Columns--');
        print(self.columns);
        print('--Subgrids--');
        print(self.submats);
        print('--Matrix--');
        for i in self.rows:
            print(i);

def checking(matrix):
    check = [True, True, True];
    for i in matrix.rows:
        if len(set(i))!=4:
            check[0] = False; break
    for i in matrix.columns:
        if len(set(i))!=4:
            check[1] = False; break
    for i in matrix.submats:
        if len(set(i))!=4:
            check[2] = False; break
    print(check);
    if False in check:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def sudoku_gen(matrix, f):
    store = list(); attempt = int(0);
    while not checking(matrix):
        while (matrix.rows in store):
            Mat = list();
            for i in range(0, 4):
                Y= shuffle(num, f);
                while Y in Mat :
                    Y = shuffle(num, f);
                Mat.append(Y);
            matrix = Matrix4(Mat);
        store.append(copy.deepcopy(matrix.rows));
        attempt = attempt + 1;
        print('----'+str(attempt));
    return matrix

#f is the frequency of shuffeling to permute list [1, 2, 3, 4].
#This will be used in function shuffle(x, freq) and sudoku_gen(matrix, f).
f = 20;
#You may use different combinations of this parameter.  

Mat = list(); num=[1,2,3,4];
for i in range(0, 4):
    Y = shuffle(num, f); print(Y);
    Mat.append(Y);

Matrix = Matrix4(Mat);
new_mat = list();
new_mat.append(sudoku_gen(Matrix, f));

#This is the number of sudoku-matrix to be generated.
number_of_sudoku = 5;

while len(new_mat)<number_of_sudoku:
    repeat = True;
    while repeat:
        repeat = False;
        result = sudoku_gen(Matrix, f);
        #Uniqueness test:
        for i in new_mat:
            if i.rows == result.rows:
                repeat = True; break        
    new_mat.append(sudoku_gen(Matrix, f));
idx = 1;
for i in new_mat:
    print('***** Matrix-'+str(idx)+' *****');
    idx = idx+1;
    i.show();
```

This code is available on https://github.com/anbarief/sudoku-gen